# QGIS: Buffer around external border of a country based on federal state borders

Tags: qgis, buffer

based on the question "[How to add state polygon information to a city point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180591/qgis-several-layers-query)" I have an additional question:

With "join attributes by location" I got a layer that constist of the city names with the corresponding ferdale state names. There is just one problem: Lots of the cities are located on the coast and maybe they are not accurate located.

My idea is to create a buffer-zone around the external border.
Is there a possibility in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you want to

Run the buffer process from the menu: TOOLS -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Buffer(s)

I am not sure an appropriate buffer distance for you, but be sure to set that and run the tool.

here are some tutorials with pics explaining it in further detail:

https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html

https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Buffer_with_QGIS

[QGIS - Create buffer in meters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/106988/qgis-create-buffer-in-meters)